# Showing the browser’s ‘select file’ dialog when focusing input[type=file] through keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-navigation, file-io, input-type-file

As the title says, I want the ‘select file’ dialog to open when a certain `input` gets focus by tabbing through the form fields (using keyboard navigation). By default, the ‘select file’ window only opens when the field is clicked.

I put up a page on JS Bin for this issue: http://jsbin.com/areba/edit

Currently, this page consists of the following code:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
 <head> 
  <title>Sandbox</title> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <form> 
   <input type="text"> 
   <input type="file">
  </form>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
     $(this).next('input[type=file]').css('background', 'lime').trigger('click');
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body> 
</html>
```

As you can see, there is a text input and a file input. The idea is that when the text input receives focus, the file input gets ‘clicked’ or whatever and the ‘select file’ window opens.

The `.css('background', 'lime')` statement seems to work fine; however, invoking `.trigger('click')` on the file input seems to do nothing at all.

(I realize this might cause an accessibility problem, so please, let’s not discuss that. Thanks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in IE and Safari (I think), but not in Opera or Firefox, as they haven't implemented the click() event for file upload elements - edit: yet.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you would be able to do activate the dialog for security reasons. A real click event has to happen, depending on the browser.

I know Flash/Flex have this requirement.